# Rails.. Bring Element and children and other parents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So, I have this situation

```
class AnamnesisModel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :anamnesis_questions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :anamnesis_questions
end

class AnamnesisQuestion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :anamnesis_model
  belongs_to :question
end

class Question < ApplicationRecord
end
```

And , I wanna find an specific AnamnesisModel, something like this

```
AnamnesisModel.find(1)
```

and then, bring all the objects, such as AnamnesisModel,AnamnesisQuestion and Question, executing only one (or maybe two) sql.

I've been trying stuffs like, preload, eager_load, include, but, in the end.. to bring Question, it executes one sql for each AnamnesisQuestions.

```
Question Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 66], ["LIMIT", 1]
]
  Question Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 67], ["LIMIT", 1]
]
  Question Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 68], ["LIMIT", 1]
]
  Question Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 69], ["LIMIT", 1]
]
  Question Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 70], ["LIMIT", 1]
]
  Question Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 71], ["LIMIT", 1]
]
  Question Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 72], ["LIMIT", 1]
]
  Question Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 73], ["LIMIT", 1]
]
  Question Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 74], ["LIMIT", 1]
]
  Question Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 75], ["LIMIT", 1]
]
  Question Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 76], ["LIMIT", 1]
]
  Question Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 77], ["LIMIT", 1]
]
  Question Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 78], ["LIMIT", 1]
]
  Question Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 79], ["LIMIT", 1]
]
  Question Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 80], ["LIMIT", 1]
]
  Question Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 81], ["LIMIT", 1]
]
  Question Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 82], ["LIMIT", 1]
]
  Question Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 83], ["LIMIT", 1]
]
  Question Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 84], ["LIMIT", 1]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`includes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes) has a number of useful things you can do, for instance

> Loading nested relationships is possible using a Hash:
>
> ```
> users = User.includes(:address, friends: [:address, :followers])
> ```

So, we can do something like:

```
model = Anamnesis.includes(anamnesis_questions: :question).find(1)
#  Anamnesis Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "anamneses".* FROM "anamneses" WHERE "anamneses"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
#  AnamnesisQuestion Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "anamnesis_questions".* FROM "anamnesis_questions" WHERE "anamnesis_questions"."anamnesis_id" = 1
#  Question Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21)
# => #<Anamnesis id: 1, created_at: "2017-07-15 22:17:33", updated_at: "2017-07-15 22:17:33">
```

and then you don't need any further queries for

```
# No SQL queries generated
model.anamnesis_questions.each { |aq| puts aq.question.id }
```

Comment: It seems to be the best solution by now ..I Will try this